# Single neuron in neural network using c++

Tags: c++, neural-network

I am trying to write a simple neuron function in c++ similar to this image. I am using sigmoid function as activation function.
[image]

This is my c++ neuron function

```
#include<math.h>

double neuron(double layer_inputs[],int iter)
{

  // Feed forwarding single neuron
    double network=0;
    double bias=1;
    double activation;

    //get number of elements in the layer
    const int num=sizeof(layer_inputs)/sizeof(layer_inputs[0]);
    double weight[num];

    for ( int i = 0; i < num; i++ )
    {
        if(iter==0)
        {
        //first time assigning random weights
            weight[i]=rand();
        }

        //feed forwarding summation
        network=network+(layer_inputs[i]*weight[i]+bias);


    }

    activation= 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-network)); //sigmoid activation function

return activation;
}
```

The problem is I dont know whether I made any logical error in my code. `iter` is the iteration variable to check if the neuron is activating for first time. Is my writing the neuron in a neural network correct.

EDIT:

Even though not from a programmatic or quant background I am fascinated about programming,neural networks and artificial intelligence. I hve used inbuilt functions in `caret` R but for more understanding  I want to create a simple neural network from scratch. I learned most of the basics from internet and I am posting my codes here because I am sure I made some illogical but executing script.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <math.h>//pow, exp
#include "sqrtnn.h" //neuron()


int main()
{

    double input[]= {1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100};
    double output[]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    //number of layers
    double layer=3;
    double output_network[10];
    double error[10];
    double learning_rate=0.02;
    //number of iterations
    int iter=10;
    int input_num=sizeof(input)/sizeof(input[0]);
    std::cout<<"Simple  neural network for solving square root\n \nINPUT -> OUTPUT\n\n";
    for ( int i = 0; i < iter; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < input_num; j++ )
        {
            for ( int k = 0; k < layer; k++ )
            {
                //feed forwarding
                output_network[j] =neuron(input,i) ; //sigmoid activation function

                //back propogation
                error[j]=1/2*pow(output[j]-output_network[j],2);//error function
                std::cout<<input[j]<<" -> "<< output[j]<<"= "<< error[j] <<"\n";


            }
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you written some unit tests? Define some inputs and expected outputs and write unit tests to test your function against those inputs.

Comment: You need to do your own logical testing before posting up here

Comment: In theory it looks ok - as long as you seed random somewhere. Why have you asked? Is there a specific thing you are concerned about? As the comments say, try writing some tests.

Comment: `sizeof(layer_inputs)` is equal to `sizeof(double *)`. Maybe the problem lies here?

Comment: The `iter==0` test isn't very efficient. You might want to initialize the weights elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

You're writing C code, not C++. C arrays don't know their own size. Use `std::vector<double> layer_inputs` so you can call `layer_inputs.size()`.

Other C bits in your code: don't declare variables until you need them; you have declared `activation` far too early. In fact, I wouldn't define it at all - just `return 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-network));`.

Comment: Technically, the new C spec also allows declaring variables when you need them, right?

Answer (score 0):

here is the problem just convert `double input[10]` to `double input[]`because it is c++ not c do this on output array also and it is not a training neural network model because actual (ready maid inputs/outputs) are provided and  `double learning_rate = 0.02;` is declared not used anywhere.

Comment: i think you take random or users data and find sqrt with your neural network then you will get error other wise no error occurs.it is very good code. modify this you will get wonderful outcomes .i appreciate your work.